# remove non latin characters in file names

Tags: python

I have been working on a problem where I take lots of Mac files and folders and need to archive them on windows servers data tape.
There are problems and hangups when I get to .DS_store files, and other mac characters.  So I need to basically do a cleanup step before the move to windows.
One thing left to do is look for non-latin chars like the bullet character, and remove them or replace them with _ (underscore character).  I am having trouble getting that to work.
Complains about indentation when run, and any manipulation by me has been fruitless.   Is the code area for dealing with non-latin chars OK?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/python

import os
import sys

# Help function
def showhelp():
    print "Usage: delete-dsstore.py PATH"
    print "Example: delete-dsstore.py /Users/angelito"


if len(sys.argv) > 1:

    # Check if parameter is a dir
    if os.path.isdir(sys.argv[1]):

        # Clear file counter
        i = 0;

        # Get path
        path  = sys.argv[1];

        # Runs through all files in the directory
        for root, sub, files in os.walk(path):

            for file in files:

                # Checks if exists .DS_Store file
                if file == ".DS_Store":

                    # Get full path of current .DS_Store file
                    fullpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
                    print "Deleting " + fullpath

                    # Remove file
                    os.remove(fullpath)
                    i += 1

                # Checks if exists .localized file
                if file == ".localized":

                    # Get full path of current .localized file
                    fullpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
                    print "Deleting " + fullpath

                    # Remove file
                    os.remove(fullpath)
                    i += 1

        # Runs through all files in the directory
        for root, sub, files in os.walk(path):

            # Checks if exists non latin characters like bullets in file names, and delete characters
            for file in files:
                os.rename(file, file.encode('latin-1', 'ignore'))

            # Get full path of current non latin character file
                fullpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
                print "Modifying " + fullpath

                i += 1

        print str(i) + " files deleted";

    elif sys.argv[1] == '--help':

        # Show help message
        showhelp()

    else:

        print "Argument must be a valid directory"

else:

    showhelp()
```

Comment: Do you really mean Latin or non-ASCII? E.g. `ễ` is a perfectly fine Latin character.

Comment: yeah I mean any characters that are not ASCII 1-255. I do not get what is wrong with my code:

Comment: ASCII is only 0-127, though ...

Comment: Sorry I included extended character set, which I do not want.  plugging in code below does not work in the script.

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `code` `# Checks if exists non latin characters like bullets in file names, and delete characters
                for file in files:
                    p = file.compile(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]')
                    #os.rename(file, file.encode('latin-1', 'ignore'))
                    os.rename(file, p.sub('_', file))

                    # Get full path of current non latin character file
                    fullpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
                    print("Modifying " + fullpath)
                    i += 1`

Comment: is re.compile() the same as regex.sub()

Answer (score 3):

If you really mean Latin characters and not ASCII, then [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) is your friend:

```
s = u'汉语 / 漢語; Hànyǔ or 中文; Zhōngwén.tmp'

> print regex.sub(u'\p{^Latin}', u'_', s)
_________Hànyǔ_or_____Zhōngwén_tmp

> print regex.sub(u'\p{^Latin}+', u'_', s)
_Hànyǔ_or_Zhōngwén_tmp

> print '.'.join( regex.sub(u'\p{^Latin}+', u'_', t)
                  for t in s.rsplit('.', 1) )
_Hànyǔ_or_Zhōngwén.tmp
```

And if you want to preserve what character was replaced:

```
> print '.'.join( regex.subf(u'\p{^Latin}',
                             lambda m: '_%04x' % ord(m[0]),
                             t)
                  for t in s.rsplit('.', 1) )
_6c49_8bed_0020_002f_0020_6f22_8a9e_003b_0020Hànyǔ_0020or_0020_4e2d_6587_003b_0020Zhōngwén.tmp
```

Reversible with:

```
regex.subf('_([0-9a-f]{4})', lambda m: unichr(int(m[1], 16)), s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
p = re.compile(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]')
filename = p.sub('_', filename)
```

For example:

```
>>> p.sub('_', 'this-is-it')
'this_is_it'
>>> p.sub('_', 'â ê bla bla bla')
'______bla_bla_bla'
```

Comment: Nice clean output, but it removes valid filename characters like appos, comma, brackets ...

Comment: Then add them to the regex patterns. I don't know what OP is really want, so I provide a generic answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
safe_fname = 'â ê bla bla bla'.encode("ascii","ignore")
```

(assuming you mean ascii... not latin)

Comment: I guess you need to `.replace('?', '_')`, too, because you cannot use question marks in file names in Windows AFAK.